# PowerShell Move Files with specific names

Tags: powershell

I need a PS script that can copy specific files from one directory to another.

Main Goal: I want to copy all files from Month folder (November) to DirectoryX. HOWEVER,I only want to move the files with specific names from an .xlsx file with the column named FileName. So say there are 3,000 filesnames in the .xlsx file with unique filenames. This is a monthly report that is generated from SSMS.

Process: .xlsx file is created with data. The column for the filenames is FileName. I want to cross reference those filenames with the November folder and copy those files to a new directory to upload to the client.

Folder Structure:

Year: 2022
Month: 11
Day: 09

File Naming Convention: CA09a37ce4c69f31997c8656df274749c4.mp3.

Not sure the best way to do this. I have looked around on here and nothing that really suits what I need.

I really hope this makes sense and someone can guide me in the right direction. Thank you so much in advance.

We use an in-house application. I can add a PS script to it. I am brand new to Powershell so this is more complex than what I can handle.

Comment: is the file a full excel .xlsx, or can you get a .csv/text file? Is the folder structure supposed to be like`[...]\2022\11\09\file.mp3`?

Comment: Yes that folder structure is correct, and client wants .xlsx only so I have to use that file type :/

Answer (score 0):

Install the [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.8.2) module, then this should work if you update the paths:

```
# import the FileNames column from excel file
$FileNames = Import-Excel 'C:\folder\file.xlsx' | Select -ExpandProperty FileName | Sort

# specify folder(s) to search
$Month = '11'
$SearchFolder = "C:\SourceFiles\2022\$Month"  # all days in month

# get the list of existing source files, filtered by the imported file names
$SourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $SearchFolder -Recurse -File |
  Where Name -In $FileNames

# optionally check for missing files
$MissingFiles = Compare-Object $SourceFiles.Name $FileNames
If ($MissingFiles) { 
  Write-Warning "Could not find $($MissingFiles.Count) source files in $SearchFolder" 
  $MissingFiles.InputObject
}

# copy files to separate folder
$SourceFiles | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Uploads\"
```

It's not the most efficient thing, but it should be easy enough to modify as needed